# refresh javascript after addding a div

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

im doing a trello copy
im using a modal to insert adjacent html
after adding that i wanna refresh the javascript src so that it can detect the div this is the code

```
      <div id="ColCreate" class="fab tooltip"><span class="tooltiptext">Add Column</span>+</div>
      <div id="CreateCol" class="ColCreate">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <span class="close">&times;</span>
               <h2>Create an column</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <label for="cname">Column Name</label>
               <input id="cnamei" type="text" name="cnamei"><br>
               <button onclick="finish()" class="Finish">Finish</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <h3></h3>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="container" class="container">
         
      </div>
      <script src="./index.js"></script>
      <script src="./modal.js"></script>
      <script src="./Drag.js"></script>
```

this is the javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementById("CreateCol");

var btn = document.getElementById("ColCreate");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

var finish = document.getElementsByClassName("Finish")[0];

var list1 = "<div><h3>"
var list2 = "</h3><ul id=\"list-1\" class=\"sortable\"><li id=\"fake\" class=\"hidden\"></li><li id=\"item-1\"><a href=\"#1\">Link 01</a></li><li id=\"item-2\"><a href=\"#2\">Link 02</a></li><li id=\"item-3\"><a href=\"#3\">Link 03</a></li><li id=\"item-4\"><a href=\"#4\">Link 04</a></li><li id=\"item-5\"><a href=\"#5\">Link 05</a></li><li id=\"item-6\"><a href=\"#6\">Link 06</a></li></ul></div>"

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

var finish = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cnamei").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("container");
  modal.style.display = "none";
  var list = `${list1}${x}${list2}`
  y.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', list);
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

modal.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

i wanna refresh the javascript so that dragging works

Comment: You can't *refresh* JavaScript, but you can re-run a function or add new event listeners. I'm guessing that the logic for dragging is in the `Drag.js` file. There you should either listen for your events with event delegation or call a function that sets new event listeners after the DOM has been updated. Show us the code and we'll be able to tell.

Comment: sorry but im a newbie to javascript and script tags so can you put the code in the answer plz

Comment: Well, noob or not, I can't help you without you sharing the code that causes the issue.